# Can I call rs.initiate() and rs.Add() from node.js using the MongoDb driver?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, kubernetes

I'm looking to automate the process of setting up a MongoDb replica set via a sidecar when using Docker and Kubernetes.

**The above setup isn't terribly important**, what it boils down to is that I need to be able to call the mongo replica set commands (e.g. `rs.initiate()`, `rs.add('anotherserver')`, `rs.conf()`, `rs.reconfig()`, etc) from a node.js application.

Note: it doesn't have to be from a node application, if someone knows of another way of getting the same thing done, please share your thoughts.

**UPDATE:** I was able to get this working and have made the sidecar open source for others to use.

- https://github.com/leportlabs/mongo-k8s-sidecar
- https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/leportlabs/mongo-k8s-sidecar

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### How are the replica set admin helpers implemented?

The [`rs.*` replica set admin helpers](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/js-replication/) in the `mongo` shell are wrappers for MongoDB commands which you can send from any driver.

You can see which command(s) each shell helper wraps by referring to the MongoDB documentation:

- [`rs.initiate()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/rs.initiate/) provides a wrapper around the [`replSetInitiate`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/replSetInitiate/) database command.
- [`rs.add()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/rs.add/) provides a wrapper around some of the functionality of the [`replSetReconfig`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/replSetReconfig/) database command and the corresponding mongo shell helper `rs.reconfig()`.
- [`rs.conf()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/rs.conf/) wraps the [`replSetGetConfig`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/rs.conf/) database command.

Note that the `mongo` shell helpers may do some extra validation or manipulation of configs as they are intended to be used via the interactive `mongo` shell.

You can confirm how any of the shell helpers are implemented by invoking the command in the shell without trailing parentheses, eg:

```
> rs.initiate
function (c) { return db._adminCommand({ replSetInitiate: c }); }
```

#### Calling replica set database commands from Node.js

The equivalent logic can be implemented via the Node.js driver API using [`command()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Admin.html#command):

```
// Rough equivalent of rs.initiate()
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', function(err, db) {

  // Use the admin database for commands
  var adminDb = db.admin();

  // Default replica set conf
  var conf = {};

  adminDb.command({replSetInitiate: conf}, function(err, info) {
     console.log(info);
  });
});
```

> Note: it doesn't have to be from a node application, if someone knows of another way of getting the same thing done, please share your thoughts.

Rather than reimplementing the replica set helpers in Node.js, you could invoke a `mongo` shell with the `--eval` command to run the shell helper (tip: include `--quiet` to suppress unnecessary messages).

For example, calling from your Node app:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var rsAdmin = exec('mongo --eval "var res = rs.initiate(); printjson(res)" --quiet', function (error, stdout, stderr) {
   // output is in stdout
   console.log(stdout);
});
```

Comment: +1 Thanks @Stennie, I actually stumbled across one of your other answers on this topic and am in the process of implementing it... works like a treat. Stay tuned!

Comment: Managed to get all this working thanks @Stennie, see my question edit for more info if you were interested.

Comment: Super helpful, I wish I could give you 5 upvotes for that one!