# Add entries to containers /etc//hosts When spinning up a pod with pod1.yaml or pod1.json

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I hope everyone here is doing good. I am trying to find a way to add entries to the containers /etc/hosts file while spinning up a pod. I was just wondering to know if there is any option/parameter that I could mention in my "pod1.json" which adds the entries to the containers /etc/hosts when its being created. Something like "--add-host node1.example.com:${node1ip}" that serves the same purpose for docker as shown below.

```
docker run \
--name mongo \
-v /home/core/mongo-files/data:/data/db \
-v /home/core/mongo-files:/opt/keyfile \
--hostname="node1.example.com" \
--add-host node1.example.com:${node1ip} \
--add-host node2.example.com:${node2ip} \
--add-host node3.example.com:${node3ip} \
-p 27017:27017 -d mongo:2.6.5 \
--smallfiles \
--keyFile /opt/keyfile/mongodb-keyfile \
--replSet "rs0"
```

Any pointers are highly appreciated. Thank you.

Regards,
Aj

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes uses the [IP-per-pod model](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/design/networking.md). If I understand correctly, you want to create three mongo pods, and write IP addresses of the three pods in `/etc/hosts` of each container. Modifying the `/etc/host` files directly might not be a good idea for many reasons (e.g., the pod may die and be replaced).

For peer discovery in kubernetes, you need to

1. Find out the IP addresses of the peers.
2. Update your application with the addresses.

(1) is achievable using [Headless Service](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/user-guide/services.md#headless-services). (2) requires your to write a sidecar container to run along side with your mongo containers, performs (1), and configures your application. The sidecar container is highly application-specific and you may want to read some [related stackoverflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30041699/can-i-call-rs-initiate-and-rs-add-from-node-js-using-the-mongodb-driver) about doing this for mongodb.

As for (1), you can create a [Headless Service](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/user-guide/services.md#headless-services) by using this [service.yaml](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/examples/nodesjs-mongodb/mongo-service.yaml) with the clusterIP set to None.

```
spec:
  clusterIP: None
```

Then, you can create a replication controller which creates the desired number of mongo pods. For example, you can use [mongo-controller.yaml](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/examples/nodesjs-mongodb/mongo-controller.yaml), replaces the `gcePersistentDisk` with a desired local disk volume type (e.g. [`emptyDir`](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/user-guide/volumes.md#emptydir) or [`hostPath`](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/user-guide/volumes.md#hostpath)), and change the replica number to 3.

Each of the mongo pod will be assigned an IP address automatically, and is labeled with `name=mongo`. The headless service uses a label selector to find the pods. When querying DNS with the service name from a node or a container, it will return a list of IP addresses of the mongo pods.

E.g.,

```
$ host mongo
mongo.default.svc.cluster.local has address 10.245.0.137
mongo.default.svc.cluster.local has address 10.245.3.80
mongo.default.svc.cluster.local has address 10.245.1.128
```

You can get the addresses in the sidecar container you wrote and configure mongodb-specific accordingly.

Comment: Thank You! Yu-Ju Hong. Sorry for the late response. I wasn't using any DNS with my Kubernetes cluster before. Now I have skyDNS set up and I am using headless service for mongodb. Now I am able to see all the entries in /etc/hosts (When a pod is created).

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do this in the way that you initially were expecting to.

Thanks to this answer for helping me get there - https://stackoverflow.com/a/33888424/370364

You can use the following approach to shove hosts into your container's /etc/hosts file

```
command: ["/bin/sh","-c"]
args: ["echo '192.168.200.200 node1.example.com' >> /etc/hosts && commandX"]
```

If you want to dynamically set the ip at pod start time you can create a pod from stdin and pass it through sed to perform substitution before passing it to kubectl.

So the pod yaml would look like the following

```
command: ["/bin/sh","-c"]
args: ["echo 'NODE_1_IP node1.example.com' >> /etc/hosts && commandX"]
```

Then execute it with

```
cat pod1.yaml | sed -- "s|NODE_1_IP|${node1ip}|" | kubectl create -f -
```

I realise that this is not way that kubernetes intended for this kind of thing to be achieved but we are using this for starting up a test pod locally and we need to point it at the default network device on the local machine. Creating a service just to satisfy the test pod seems like overkill. So we do this instead.

Comment: As the OP question is defined, this should be the accepted answer. I have a similar use case where an app inside a container needs hosts file entries for hosts outside kubernetes entirely. Since this is a stop-gap solution, it doesn't make sense to have the devs rewrite the app to include these hosts, instead I can just add hosts file entries to the handful of hosts the app needs to connect to... and move on.