# How to set multiple commands in one yaml file with Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

In this official document, it can run command in a yaml config file:

> https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: hello-world
spec:  # specification of the pod’s contents
  restartPolicy: Never
  containers:
  - name: hello
    image: "ubuntu:14.04"
    env:
    - name: MESSAGE
      value: "hello world"
    command: ["/bin/sh","-c"]
    args: ["/bin/echo \"${MESSAGE}\""]
```

If I want to run more than one command, how to do?

Answer (score 284, accepted):

```
command: ["/bin/sh","-c"]
args: ["command one; command two && command three"]
```

**Explanation:** The `command ["/bin/sh", "-c"]` says "run a shell, and execute the following instructions". The args are then passed as commands to the shell. In shell scripting a semicolon separates commands, and `&&` conditionally runs the following command if the first succeed. In the above example, it always runs `command one` followed by `command two`, and only runs `command three` if `command two` succeeded.

**Alternative:** In many cases, some of the commands you want to run are probably setting up the final command to run. In this case, building your own [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/reference/builder/) is the way to go. Look at the [RUN](https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/reference/builder/#run) directive in particular.

Comment: Yes, very valid, however, I think there are also good use cases to extend `command` as it overrides the Dockerfile's `Entrypoint` ;)

Comment: Any idea on how to do this with container lifecycle? It has no args

Comment: @aclokay you can just specify the arguments as additional command strings. The separation between command & args in the Container is just to make overriding the arguments easier. They are functionally equivalent.

Comment: what -c does here?

Comment: @Abdul it means run the script provided as an argument, rather than starting an interactive shell or loading the script from a file.

Comment: if you keep `&` instead of `&&` that means, it's not compulsory that the first command must be succeed.if first command is not succeed then it will go for the next, if you use `&` like this: `args: ["command one; command two & command three"]`

Comment: This makes no sense to me... Isn't `-c` an argument? Then why the heck would you put it inside `command` and not `args`? Then why not put everything inside `command` since that means that `command` does not have to contain only the executable but it can also add arguments... why bother separating the two? Why wouldn't `command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "command one; command two && command three""]` work exactly like your example? This would make sense if you had to write `command: "/bin/sh"` and then `args: ["-c", "..."]`

Comment: Why are command and args of list type instead of string.

Comment: @YogiGhorecha In sh/bash/zsh a single `&` means to run that command in the background. You are probably thinking of `;`

Comment: @GACy20 apparently `command` can be used alone without `args`. You would use `args` alone to override the docker `Cmd` args. Using `command` alone overrides `EntryPoint` and `Cmd` from docker. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66078726/4524081 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/67925795/4524081

Answer (score 188):

My preference is to multiline the args, this is simplest and easiest to read. Also, the script can be changed without affecting the image, just need to restart the pod. For example, for a mysql dump, the container spec could be something like this:

```
containers:
  - name: mysqldump
    image: mysql
    command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
    args:
      - echo starting;
        ls -la /backups;
        mysqldump --host=... -r /backups/file.sql db_name;
        ls -la /backups;
        echo done;
    volumeMounts:
      - ...
```

The reason this works is that yaml actually concatenates all the lines after the "-" into one, and sh runs one long string "echo starting; ls... ; echo done;".

Comment: Nice, but when you request an edit with kubectl, it will be in one line again. :)

Comment: @sekrett oh no ! :(

Comment: This worked quite nicely - the key is the semicolon on each line. This is a particularly good solution when the commands are many and would be multiline with the solution above. Makes git diff a breeze

Comment: This is what I was looking for. using the environment variable as arguments with this solution works nicely.

Comment: +1 Beautiful, plus multi-line commands work perfectly:
`command: ['/bin/bash', '-c']`
`args:`
`- exec &> /path/to/redirected/program.output;`
`  python /program.py\`
`    --key1=val1\`
`    --key2=val2\`
`    --key3=val3`

Comment: way cleaner and it works better, thanks for the idea.

Comment: But what if one command is so long (many parameters) that for formatting purposes one wants to break that into multiple lines using `\`? This seems to fail for us and the next line after `\` is interpreted as new command instead of as a continuation.

Comment: @Spenhouet Long scripts should instead be refactored into a `.sh` file and put in the image. If you're using a third-party image, create a custom image that has `FROM third-party-image` and just add the `.sh` there.

Answer (score 75):

If you're willing to use a Volume and a ConfigMap, you can [mount ConfigMap data](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#populate-a-volume-with-data-stored-in-a-configmap) as a script, and then run that script:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-configmap
data:
  entrypoint.sh: |-
    #!/bin/bash
    echo "Do this"

    echo "Do that"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: my-container
    image: "ubuntu:14.04"
    command:
    - /bin/entrypoint.sh
    volumeMounts:
    - name: configmap-volume
      mountPath: /bin/entrypoint.sh
      readOnly: true
      subPath: entrypoint.sh
  volumes:
  - name: configmap-volume
    configMap:
      defaultMode: 0700
      name: my-configmap
```

This cleans up your pod spec a little and allows for more complex scripting.

```
$ kubectl logs my-pod
Do this
Do that
```

Comment: Very cool, but I think it is simpler to have the script inline, just use multiline syntax. I show this in a separate answer.

Comment: What about when I need to pass double quotes. For example imagine this command: printf '%s @%s\n' "$(echo 'user')" "$(echo 'host')"

Comment: This is the most flexible solution

Answer (score 57):

If you want to avoid concatenating all commands into a single command with `;` or `&&` you can also get true multi-line scripts using a heredoc:

```sh
command: 
 - sh
 - "-c"
 - |
   /bin/bash <<'EOF'

   # Normal script content possible here
   echo "Hello world"
   ls -l
   exit 123

   EOF
```

This is handy for running existing bash scripts, but has the downside of requiring both an inner and an outer shell instance for setting up the heredoc.

Comment: how we can setting up the heredoc?

Comment: by doing that getting the while running ```$SHELL``` output: ```\bin\ash```

Comment: It seems like the nested shells prevent the sysout from spooling to the kubernetes logs

Answer (score 28):

I am not sure if the question is still active but due to the fact that I did not find the solution in the above answers I decided to write it down.

I use the following approach:

```
readinessProbe:
  exec:
    command:
    - sh
    - -c
    - |
      command1
      command2 && command3
```

I know my example is related to readinessProbe, livenessProbe, etc. but suspect the same case is for the container commands. This provides flexibility as it mirrors a standard script writing in Bash.

Answer (score 14):

IMHO the best option is to use YAML's native [block scalars](https://yaml-multiline.info). Specifically in this case, the *folded* style block.

By invoking `sh -c` you can pass arguments to your container as commands, but if you want to elegantly separate them with newlines, you'd want to use the *folded style block*, so that YAML will know to convert newlines to whitespaces, effectively concatenating the commands.

A full working example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: myapp
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  containers:
  - name: busy
    image: busybox:1.28
    command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
    args:
    - >
      command_1 &&
      command_2 &&
      ... 
      command_n
```

Comment: But then if you go to edit the deployment yaml, it will be in one line, unreadable again

Comment: Editing a live resource with `kubectl edit` and the likes is an anti-pattern and a bad idea anyway. Your running configuration should always match what's written on your manifests. That's what declarative configuration and version control systems are for.

Answer (score 12):

> Here is my successful run

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    run: busybox
  name: busybox
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - /bin/sh
    - -c
    - |
      echo "running below scripts"
      i=0; 
      while true; 
      do 
        echo "$i: $(date)"; 
        i=$((i+1)); 
        sleep 1; 
      done
    name: busybox
    image: busybox
```

Answer (score 11):

Here is another way to run multi line commands.

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: multiline
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - command:
        - /bin/bash
        - -exc
        - |
          set +x
          echo "running below scripts"
          if [[ -f "if-condition.sh" ]]; then
            echo "Running if success"
          else
            echo "Running if failed"
          fi
        name: ubuntu
        image: ubuntu
      restartPolicy: Never
  backoffLimit: 1
```

Answer (score 9):

Here is one more way to do it, with output logging.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    type: test
  name: nginx
spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    name: nginx
    volumeMounts:
      - name: log-vol
        mountPath: /var/mylog
    command:
        - /bin/sh
        - -c
        - >
            i=0;
            while [ $i -lt 100 ];
            do
             echo "hello $i";
             echo "$i :  $(date)" >> /var/mylog/1.log;
             echo "$(date)" >> /var/mylog/2.log;
             i=$((i+1));
             sleep 1;
            done

  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  restartPolicy: Always
  volumes:
    - name: log-vol
      emptyDir: {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to bring another possible option, secrets can be used as they are presented to the pod as volumes:

Secret example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret 
metadata:
  name: secret-script
type: Opaque
data:
  script_text: <<your script in b64>>
```

Yaml extract:

```
....
containers:
    - name: container-name
      image: image-name
      command: ["/bin/bash", "/your_script.sh"]
      volumeMounts:
        - name: vsecret-script
          mountPath: /your_script.sh
          subPath: script_text
....
  volumes:
    - name: vsecret-script
      secret:
        secretName: secret-script
```

I know many will argue this is not what secrets must be used for, but it is an option.

Answer (score 0):

migration-testing:
- step:
name: Run migration
script:
- pipe: atlassian/aws-eks-kubectl-run:2.2.1
variables:
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
CLUSTER_NAME: $CLUSTER_NAME
KUBECTL_COMMAND: exec
KUBECTL_ARGS:
- '-n'
- 'test-namespace'
- 'test-podname'
- '-it'
- '--'
- '/bin/sh'
- '-c'
- 'npm run migrate'
in place of test-podname I want to run another kubectl command to get current pod in namespace as podname is not fixed it takes some random numeric string after name provided in yaml file so that I dont have to worry about name of pod

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).