# kubernetes pod with sleep command hangs

Tags: kubernetes

I have a pod with the following config:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    name: demo
  name: demo
spec:
  containers:
    - name: demo
      image: ubuntu:14.04
      command:
        - sleep
        - "3600"
```

When I try to stop it, the SIGTERM is ignored by the sleep command, and it takes 30 seconds (the full default grace period) to stop.  I can also get on the pod and send the signal to the process (pid 1) manually, and it does not kill the pod.  How can I get sleep to die when a signal is sent to it?

Answer (score 6):

Bash [ignores SIGTERM when there are no traps](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Signals.html). You can [trap](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_02.html) SIGTERM to force an exit. For example, `trap 'exit 255' SIGTERM; sleep 3600`

Comment: I tried using this + http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33887194/how-to-set-multiple-commands-in-one-yaml-file-with-kubernetes and it still hangs :/