# k8s: Unable to read environment variable in livenessProbes exec

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to use below command to curl to the pod itself using podip as currently I don't want kubelet to request my pod for health check.

```
livenessProbe:
  exec:
    command:
    - curl
    - $POD_IP:9990/admin/ping
  initialDelaySeconds: 3
  periodSeconds: 5
```

but the env variable $POD_IP is not recognized here,

```
Could not resolve host: $POD_IP
```

How to configure this so that env var can be read by curl in the command.

**reference:**
https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.9/#execaction-v1-core

Comment: You could try the various notations {$POD_IP}, ${POD_IP}, etc..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try following :

```
command:
- bash
- -c
- curl $POD_IP:9990/admin/ping
```

Comment: More info about how to perform commands here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33887194/how-to-set-multiple-commands-in-one-yaml-file-with-kubernetes

Answer (score 0):

Try using escaping $ with \$ this has worked for me.

```
livenessProbe:
exec:
command:
- curl
- \$POD_IP:9990/admin/ping
initialDelaySeconds: 3
periodSeconds: 5
```