# How do I set multiple commands in config.yaml in kubernetes?

Tags: bash, kubernetes

I tried to use the accepted answer from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33887194/how-to-set-multiple-commands-in-one-yaml-file-with-kubernetes), but I see the following error when I apply it:

```
containers:
  - name: service
    command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
    args: ["echo 123; my_executable_binary"]
```

```
/bin/sh: 0: -c requires an argument
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this:

```
containers:
  - name: appname-service
    image: path/to/registry/image-name
    ports:
        - containerPort: 1234
    command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
    args:
      - source /env/db_cred.env;
        application-command;
```