# Add multiple commands in cronjob.yaml

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I want to run two commands in my cronjob.yaml one after each other. The first command runs a python-scipt and the second changes an environment variable in another pod. The commands added separately work.

This is what I'm trying right now (found the syntax in [How to set multiple commands in one yaml file with Kubernetes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33887194/11242263) ) but it gives me an error.

```
command:
- "/bin/bash"
- "-c"
args: ["python3 recalc.py && kubectl set env deployment recommender --env="LAST_MANUAL_RESTART=$(date)" --namespace=default"]
```

The error I get in cloudbuild:

```
error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 30: did not find expected ',' or ']'
```

(for the long line)

Comment: You need to `\"escape\"` the quotes inside the command string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have nested double quotes, try something more like this:

```
command:
- /bin/bash
- -c
- python3 recalc.py && kubectl set env deployment recommender --env="LAST_MANUAL_RESTART=$(date)" --namespace=default
```

i.e. without the outer double quotes.