# kubectl run --command vs -- arguments

Tags: kubernetes, arguments, command, kubectl, busybox

I was a little confused with below command:

```
kubectl run busybox --image=busybox --restart=Never -o yaml --dry-run -- /bin/sh -c 'echo hello;sleep 3600'
```

YAML:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    run: busybox
  name: busybox
spec:
  containers:
  - args:
    - /bin/sh
    - -c
    - echo hello;sleep 3600
    image: busybox
    name: busybox
    resources: {}
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  restartPolicy: Never
status: {}
```

I know if we don't specify parameter `--command`, then parameters after `--` will be treated as arguments.

But I wanted to know, how `/bin/sh -c "echo hello;sleep 3600"` was working in case of arguments? According to Kubernetes documentation(https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/#notes), If we specify only arguments in a POD then docker EntryPoint will be used as EntryPoint command. So the resultant command which will be executed in the docker image will be `Docker EntryPoint + kubectl arguments`.

As Busybox DockerFile does not contain any EntryPoint(https://github.com/docker-library/busybox/blob/master/musl/Dockerfile), so arguments specified in the kubectl command will only be used, so the command will look like:

`/bin/sh -c 'echo hello;sleep 3600'`

And if we specify `--command`, then according to Kubernetes documentation, DockerFile arguments(CMD) and command(EntryPoint) both will be overridden with command specified in the kubectl command, so it will look similar to above:

`/bin/sh -c 'echo hello;sleep 3600'`

So it would be same in the end.

Answer (score 57):

When working with containers in Kubernetes, you should be careful not to mix up Kubenetes `command` and Docker `Cmd`.

- the `command` field in Kubernetes corresponds to the `EntryPoint` field in Docker
- the `args` field in Kubernetes corresponds to the `Cmd` field in Docker

From [Kubernets documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/#notes):

> When you override the default `Entrypoint` and `Cmd`, these rules apply:
>
> - If you do not supply `command` or `args` for a Container, the defaults
>   defined in the Docker image are used.
> - If you supply a `command` but no `args` for a Container, only the supplied
>   `command` is used. The default `EntryPoint` and the default `Cmd` defined in
>   the Docker image are ignored.
> - If you supply only `args` for a Container, the default `Entrypoint`
>   defined in the Docker image is run with the `args` that you supplied.
> - If you supply a `command` and `args`, the default `Entrypoint` and the
>   default `Cmd` defined in the Docker image are ignored. Your `command` is
>   run with your `args`.

Answer (score 12):

To modify a command and parameter from the command line use the following command:

```
kubectl run nginx --image=nginx --command -- sleep 1000
```

Another example for the same:

```
kubectl run nginx --image=nginx --command -- python myapp.py
```

If you only want to overwrite a parameter (not the command itself) it would be:

```
kubectl run nginx --image=nginx -- 1000    #(sending the 1000 seconds to 
sleep)
```

Answer (score 6):

In this example, yes both are same. 
Lets say if an entry point (command) is set as `sleep 1000` but if your args are set as `sleep 3000` then container command is ignored and `sleep 3000` is executed.

Args takes precedence over command, and overrides command values if args exists

Comment: Your last statement could be misinterpreted (Kubernetes `command` vs Docker `Cmd`).
--> If you supply only `args` for a Container, the default `Entrypoint` defined in the Docker image is run with the `args` that you supplied.