# Kubernetes pod commands and args

Tags: kubernetes

What is the purpose of args if one could specify all arguments using command in kubernetes manifest file?
for example i can use below syntax which totally negates the usage of the args.

```
command: [ "bin/bash", "-c", "mycommand" ]
```

or also

```
command:
  - "bin/bash"
  - "-c"
  - "mycommand"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [kubectl run --command vs -- arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59248318/kubectl-run-command-vs-arguments)

Comment: You're talking about pods, not kubectl :)

Comment: @Jonas yes it helps, Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main reason to use `args:` instead of `command:` is if the container has a specific entrypoint directive that you don't want to change. For example if the Dockerfile has `ENTRYPOINT ["/myapp"]` you might put `args: [--log-level=debug]` to add that one argument without changing the path to the binary. In many cases it isn't relevant though and you just use `command:` to do it all at once.