# Kubernetes - Add container based on same image for tightly coupled websockets server in the same Pod?

Tags: laravel, docker, kubernetes, websocket

My client has a deployment requiring the following three items:

1. A Laravel app running on PHP Artisan server, port 8080.
2. A websockets server running via the LaravelWebSockets library (built in to Laravel application), port 6001.
3. A mysql database, port 3306.

The deployment is currently running with items 1 and 3. I would like to add item 2 (the websockets server).

I'd like to use a container for each of the above, in the same pod. It doesn't make any sense to me to create an entirely new deployment just to host the websockets server.

Since the proposed websockets server runs off the same Dockerized application that the Artisan server does, I am using the same image to build a matching container, using a **different port** and a **different CMD**.

Is this a good way to approach this, or is there a better way? Here is my Kubernetes file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: zebra-master
  labels:
    app: zebra-master
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: zebra-master
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: zebra-master
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: zebra-master
        image: registry/zebra-master:build-BUILDNUMBER
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        command: ["php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8080 -vvv"]
      - name: websockets-master
        image: registry/zebra-master:build-BUILDNUMBER
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6001
        command: ["php artisan websockets:serve"]
      - name: mysql
        image: mysql/mysql-server:5.7
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
        volumeMounts:
        ...
      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
      ...
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
...

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: zebra-master
  annotations:
    field.cattle.io/targetWorkloadIds: '["deployment:default:zebra-master"]'
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "8080"
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    workload: "zebra-master"
  type: ClusterIP

---

apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: zebra-master
spec:
  rules:
  - host: zebra.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: zebra-master
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /
```

Comment: 0

Any updates on this? I could not figure out the websocket with ingress, seems wss url never be upgraded on http headers.

Wondering if there is any gist or github example config for ref for the laravel websocket server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i undestand, you want to run the websocket on the zebra-master, and run the php project on the same time, i saw that you are using "command".
i found this maybe it should help you : [How to set multiple commands in one yaml file with Kubernetes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33887194/how-to-set-multiple-commands-in-one-yaml-file-with-kubernetes)

and for the port you can add this lines :

```
 ports:
 - containerPort: 8080
   name: http
 - containerPort: 6001
   name: websocket-port
```

in my case i will rebuild the images entrypoint with the websocket command.