# Run multiple scripts in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-pod

I would like to run multiple scripts as part of my Kubernetes container.
Any ideas please anyone?

```
containers:
- name: xyz
  image: ghost:0.11-alpine
  command: ["/scripts/wrapper.sh"]
  ports:
  - name: xyx
    containerPort: 2368
    protocol: TCP
```

I'm able to run one script successfully but adding in a second seems to be the issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33887194/how-to-set-multiple-commands-in-one-yaml-file-with-kubernetes

Comment: Looks like it might. 
I'll have a crack at it. Thanks.