# How to handle lot of commands in Kubernetes config.yaml?

Tags: kubernetes

In my Kubernetes config.yaml  I have:

```
command: ["sh", "-c", "command1; command2; command3;"]`
```

a lot of commands can complicate the config file and it will be hard to reat. What is the best approach here? Is it possible to create a script that will have those commands? I will be glad to see an example.

Comment: Can you treat this like any other substantial coding effort, build and test it outside containers, and then build an image around it?  (A `FROM busybox` image plus a POSIX shell script would be pretty small.)

Comment: please chech here a lot of options [How to set multiple commands in one yaml file with Kubernetes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33887194/how-to-set-multiple-commands-in-one-yaml-file-with-kubernetes)

Answer (score 1):

Two ways:

**The quick and dirty way .**

The command object a an array object in yaml so you can reformat like.

```
command:
 - "sh"
 - "-c"
 - "command1; command2; command3;"
 - "ect"
```

**A little more elegant way:**

- Create a config map object as a shell script with all your commands.
- Attach that config map as a mounted volume to your deployment/statefulset, cron , ect. object
- Call the shell script from your command

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#create-configmaps-from-files